# Kill all processes using a list of pid's in python?

Tags: python, list, kill, pid

I have a list of strings which contains the pid's to certain processes which must be killed at a certain time.

`pidList = ['1234', '1235', '1236']`

How would one run through the list first casting all elements to int, then killing the process represented by that pid?

essentially doing this:

`os.kill(int(pidList[0]), signal.SIGTERM)`

`os.kill(int(pidList[1]), signal.SIGTERM)`

`os.kill(int(pidList[2]), signal.SIGTERM)`

Comment: A for loop would be my first guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply iterate over the `pidlist`

```
for proc_id in pidlist:
   os.kill(int(proc_id), signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: worked like a charm, I am still new to python so being able to declare a variable on the fly `proc_id` isn't second nature to me yet

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension

```
[os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGTERM) for pid in pidlist]
```

also map will work

```
map(lambda x: os.kill(int(x), signal.SIGTERM), pidlist)
```

Comment: Using a `list comprehension` or `map` for side-effect is not a good idea.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I don't understand when you say side-effect. Can you please explain?

Comment: Run this thing in shell and you'll see that it leaves behind a list like `[None, None, ...]` in the memory, which is useless because you created a list in memory and never used it.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Thank you for the explanation. I got it now. But I don't think it as a bigger threat but I am not sure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Thanks for sharing the link. It is a problem then and anti pythonic also.